# The best way to do :not in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, performance

I have a menu in jQuery when you click on a link it opens up, but I want it so when you click somewhere else, anywhere else that is not the menu, it becomes hidden.

At the moment I'm binding a click event to

```
$(':not(#the_menu)')
```

But this seems like I'm binding a click event to the entire minus the menu, is there a more efficient way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this is with bubbling capture, like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   //close menu
})

$("#the_menu").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How this works is every click bubbles (unless you stop it, usually by `return false;` or [`event.stopPopagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)), so whatever you click bubbles all the way up to DOM...if a click does that, we close the menu.  If it came from **inside** the menu, we stop the bubble...so the click doesn't bubble up, triggering a close.  This approach uses only 2 event handlers instead of 1 on everything *but* the menu, so very lightweight :)

Comment: Woops had "Propogation" in there, fixed

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Cheers. Need to check the event bubbling on all the browsers though, you know what there like.

Have a bicky.

Comment: @Smickie - Luckily, jQuery normalizes the bubbling very well (with a *few* exceptions) so `click` works consistently.  The big one to watch out for is `change` not bubbling correctly in IE, making `.live("change",..)` problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Attach event to document's body (`$(body)`). Also attach another event to `#the_menu` that's block event propagation:

```
$(document.body).click(function() {
     //close menu if opened
});

$("#the_menu").click(function(e) {
     //code heere

     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about binding the menu display to hovering over the element in which it is contained?

```
$("#parentId").hover(
    function() { //!! on hovering in
        $("#targetId").attr("display","block") ;
    } ,
    function() { //!! on hovering out
        $("#targetId").attr("display","none") ;
    }
) ;
```

If it fits your goal, this seems easier to maintain.